# Use WebControl in ASP.NET MVC project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-controls

I have a class library that renders a web control (System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebControl).
This library is referenced in a lot of classic ASP.NET Web Forms projects like this in the .aspx files:

```
<foo:MyCustomControl ID="myControl" runat="server" />
```

Now there is a need to use the same control in some new ASP.NET MVC projects. From what I've read web server controls aren't compatible with ASP.NET MVC because they rely on postbacks and viewstate most of the time.
What is the best way to expose this web control to the new mvc applications without changing anything in the current control? Should I expose it as a WCF service somehow?

Comment: You might just consider rewriting the control as an [MVC Partial](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/617361/Partial-View-in-ASP-NET-MVC) instead, so you're not mixing technology.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add a WebForm (mycontrol.aspx), place your control in it as you did it before, and embed the result as an iFrame to your MVC application.